# Award different amounts by place (PHP)

Tags: php, database, arrays, foreach

What I am trying to do is create a contest script for a GPT site, and I want to be able to award the winners with different amounts that are defined in the database. For example first place would get what `reward_1` is in the data base and so on. So I am trying to make it to where when I do `mysql_query("UPDATE members SET points=points+'$reward' WHERE username='$username'")` but I need `$reward` to be different for each of the winning users.

**CLARIFICATION**
When this specific script is ran it gives out the rewards to the users if the date is >= the end date of the contest (in the code it says <= because if not I wouldn't be able to test it) but basically when it gives out the rewards I want to be able to use 1 query to do so but I want that query to give out the right rewards to the right users. For example the user who completed the most offers should get what reward_1 in the contest table says which lets say is 1000 and the second place user will get what the reward is listed as for row reward_2 like 500. The way I have it set up now it will give the same reward amount to all users instead of a different amount to each. I hope that helps!

Here is the code I have (please note that I haven't added any functions to attempt to do this as I have no idea where to start)

**UPDATE**
What I am working with is what is after all of the blocked lines and the reward amounts will be coming from the dbtable contest.

I am not sure if I have given enough of a description of what I am trying to get so if I need to clarify on anything please let me know, all your help is appreciated!

Okay so I have been working on this a little bit, trying to use arrays, please excuse this sloppiness as I am only trying to possibly get things working the way I need it to! This is the new code:

```
<?
include_once"config.php";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$query= "SELECT * FROM raffle WHERE amount>='1' ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 2";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$raff=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM raffle");
$raffle=mysql_fetch_row($raff);
$amount= $raffle[0] / 2;
$dates= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contest");
$stats= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE type='today'");
$statu= mysql_fetch_array($stats);

// while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 // $uid = $row["id"]; 
 // $username = $row["user_id"];  
 // echo "User ID = $uid 
    // <br />User Name = $username 
   // <hr />"; 
// $winners= mysql_query("UPDATE members SET points=points+'".$amount."' WHERE username='".$username."'");
// $statusu1= mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET new='".$statu['new']."' WHERE type='yesterday'");
// $statusu2= mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET cashouts='".$statu['cashouts']."' WHERE type='yesterday'");
// $statusu3= mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET complete='".$statu['complete']."' WHERE type='yesterday'");
// $announce= mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (text, home, date, text1)
// VALUES ('Rewards Cube System','',NOW(),'".$username." just won ".$amount." points in the daily raffle, Congrats!')");
 // }
 // $clear= mysql_query("UPDATE raffle SET amount='0'");
 // $clear1= mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET new='0' WHERE type='today'");
 // $clear2= mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET cashouts='0' WHERE type='today'");
 // $clear3= mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET complete='0' WHERE type='today'");
// print" DONE";



while ($dat = mysql_fetch_array($dates)) {
$places= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY entries_".$dat['type']." DESC LIMIT ".$dat['rewards']."");
if ($dat['rewards'] == 1){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 2){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 3){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 4){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3'], '4' => $dat['reward_4']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 5){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3'], '4' => $dat['reward_4'], '5' => $dat['reward_5']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 6){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3'], '4' => $dat['reward_4'], '5' => $dat['reward_5'], '6' => $dat['reward_6']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 7){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3'], '4' => $dat['reward_4'], '5' => $dat['reward_5'], '6' => $dat['reward_6'], '7' => $dat['reward_7']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 8){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3'], '4' => $dat['reward_4'], '5' => $dat['reward_5'], '6' => $dat['reward_6'], '7' => $dat['reward_7'], '8' => $dat['reward_8']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 9){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3'], '4' => $dat['reward_4'], '5' => $dat['reward_5'], '6' => $dat['reward_6'], '7' => $dat['reward_7'], '8' => $dat['reward_8'], '9' => $dat['reward_9']);
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 10){
$reward = array ('1' => $dat['reward_1'], '2' => $dat['reward_2'], '3' => $dat['reward_3'], '4' => $dat['reward_4'], '5' => $dat['reward_5'], '6' => $dat['reward_6'], '7' => $dat['reward_7'], '8' => $dat['reward_8'], '9' => $dat['reward_9'], '10' => $dat['reward_10']);
}
while ($place = mysql_fetch_array($places)) {
if(time() <= strtotime($dat['date_2'])) {
foreach($reward as $rew)
print" {$dat['name']}  {$place['username']} {$rew} <br>";
}
else {
print" no contests ready for rewards given";
}
}
}
?>
```

It kind of gives me the results I want, but it duplicates it for each so it gives me:

```
Monthly Offer Contest Faiz66 2500
Monthly Offer Contest Faiz66 1000
Monthly Offer Contest Faiz66 500
Monthly Offer Contest taras 2500
Monthly Offer Contest taras 1000
Monthly Offer Contest taras 500
Monthly Offer Contest admin 2500
Monthly Offer Contest admin 1000
Monthly Offer Contest admin 500
Monthly Referral Contest taras 2500
Monthly Referral Contest taras 1000
Monthly Referral Contest taras 500
Monthly Referral Contest kira423 2500
Monthly Referral Contest kira423 1000
Monthly Referral Contest kira423 500
Monthly Referral Contest Faiz66 2500
Monthly Referral Contest Faiz66 1000
Monthly Referral Contest Faiz66 500
```

Which is repeating the 3 rewards for each winner, but I need it to look like this:

```
Monthly Offer Contest Faiz66 2500
Monthly Offer Contest taras 1000
Monthly Offer Contest admin 500
Monthly Referral Contest taras 2500
Monthly Referral Contest kira423 1000
Monthly Referral Contest Faiz66 500
```

Maybe arrays aren't the best fix for this, but if it is, I guess I need to know how to make it look like the table above rather than the first one that it is giving me now.

Comment: And I do apologize ahead of time, I am rather new to PHP and my coding is more than sloppy!

Comment: _So I am trying to make it to where when I do mysql_query("UPDATE members SET points=points+'$reward' WHERE username='$username'") but I need $reward to be different for each of the winning users._  ... Can you edit this part of your question to clarify?

Comment: @JustinPearce I have updated the post, I hope that I was able to make it more understandable.

Comment: It would help if we could see some db scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a break with this code and reading up on some other ways it could be achieved I finally came up with a working solution.

It may not be the best, but it does work. I am open to any other solutions anyone may have!

```
<?
include_once"config.php";
include_once"test/includes.php";
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$dates=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contest");
$timestamp = time();

while ($dat = mysql_fetch_array($dates)) {
$places="(SELECT * FROM `".$dat['name']."` ORDER BY `completed` DESC LIMIT ".$dat['rewards'].")";
$results=mysql_query($places);

if ($dat['rewards'] == 1){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 2){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 3){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 4){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 5){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4'].",".$dat['reward_5']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 6){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4'].",".$dat['reward_5'].",".$dat['reward_6']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 7){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4'].",".$dat['reward_5'].",".$dat['reward_6'].",".$dat['reward_7']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 8){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4'].",".$dat['reward_5'].",".$dat['reward_6'].",".$dat['reward_7'].",".$dat['reward_8']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 9){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4'].",".$dat['reward_5'].",".$dat['reward_6'].",".$dat['reward_7'].",".$dat['reward_8'].",".$dat['reward_9']."";
}
else if ($dat['rewards'] == 10){
$reward = "".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4'].",".$dat['reward_5'].",".$dat['reward_6'].",".$dat['reward_7'].",".$dat['reward_8'].",".$dat['reward_9'].",".$dat['reward_10']."";
}

$rewardsa = explode(",", $reward);
$i=0;

// Offers Contest

if(time() <= $dat['date_2'] && $dat['type'] == offer) {
while ($place = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
print" {$dat['name']}  {$place['username']}  {$rewardsa[$i]}<br>";
if($dat['r_type'] == points){
$winners= mysql_query("UPDATE members SET points=points+'".$rewardsa[$i]."' WHERE username='".$place['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$shout=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shout (id, username, datetime, shout) VALUES ('','".$shoutname."','".$timestamp."','".$place['username']." has just won ".$rewardsa[$i]." points in the ".$dat['name']."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
if($dat['r_type'] == cash){
$winners= mysql_query("UPDATE members SET cash=cash+'".$rewardsa[$i]."' WHERE username='".$place['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$shout=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shout (id, username, datetime, shout) VALUES ('','".$shoutname."','".$timestamp."','".$place['username']." has just won $".$rewardsa[$i]." in the ".$dat['name']."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
$i++;
if($winners && $shout){
$delete=mysql_query("DROP TABLE `".$dat['name']."`");
}
}
}

// Referral Contest

if(time() <= $dat['date_2'] && $dat['type'] == referral) {
while ($place = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
print" {$dat['name']}  {$place['username']}  {$rewardsa[$i]}<br>";
if($dat['r_type'] == points){
$winners= mysql_query("UPDATE members SET points=points+'".$rewardsa[$i]."' WHERE username='".$place['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$shout=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shout (id, username, datetime, shout) VALUES ('','".$shoutname."','".$timestamp."','".$place['username']." has just won ".$rewardsa[$i]." points in the ".$dat['name']."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
if($dat['r_type'] == cash){
$winners= mysql_query("UPDATE members SET cash=cash+'".$rewardsa[$i]."' WHERE username='".$place['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$shout=mysql_query("INSERT INTO shout (id, username, datetime, shout) VALUES ('','".$shoutname."','".$timestamp."','".$place['username']." has just won $".$rewardsa[$i]." in the ".$dat['name']."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
$i++;
if($winners && $shout){
$delete=mysql_query("DROP TABLE `".$dat['name']."`");
}
}
}

}
?>
```

Comment: I would recommend looking into `switch` statements for this type of thing... Very helpful, and a lot less `if` statements...